# How to handle a ESP8266 webserver only to the access point?

Tags: esp8266, web-server

I'm developing a application that needs to be somewhat secure, so to configure the parameters it handles a GPIO interrupt (from a button) to open a server, that lets you configure it. The problem is that it is configured to send an email, so it is connected to the wifi.

With this in mind, I need to detect the source of the connection so I can serve the html only to the access point connections.

Is it possible?

Comment: I think what you want is that it's only accessible on the local network, and not from the internet, right?

Comment: Not only the local, no. I don't really know the exact terms, but I create a WiFi with my ESP and I want only people accessing from this exclusive WiFi to be able to change the configuration. Someone in the internet or accessing the same WiFi my esp is connected to gets rejected.

Comment: When the flag from the interrupt is 1, it puts the WebServer in STA_AP mode, I want it only be accessible via the AP side of the WebServer. I don't know if this clarifies.

Comment: So it's set to both be a client on the Wifi that's connected to the internet, and be an Accesspoint at the same time. Now it makes sense. (I didn't even know the ESP could do that.) I think you can filter based on IP address.

Comment: Maybe this is a good solution that I simply overlooked. I'll take a look.

Comment: Yep, thats absolutely simple. My access point is a 192.168.4.XXX and my LAN ip is 192.168.88.XXX, I can filter it very very easily. Thanks for the light.

Comment: You could also use the less used 10.x.x.x private range, to make it less likely that the network uses the same IP range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not documented, but you can construct WiFiServer or ESP8266WebServer with IP address. If you use the IP address of the AP, the server will be available only on the SoftAP. If you use the IP address of the station, the server will be available only on STA interface.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

WiFiServer telneServer(23);

void setup() {
  ...
  telneServer = WiFiServer(WiFi.softAPIP(), 23);
//  telneServer = WiFiServer(WiFi.localIP(), 23);
  telneServer.begin();
```

Comment: Thanks! I had already solved with the comment from above, but your answer seemed a lot more elegant, so I tried and it works just fine!

I just used had to declare the server with the IP and configure the softAP to be the same using: `ESP8266WebServer server(local_ip,80)` and `WiFi.softAPConfig(local_ip, local_ip, IPAddress(255, 255, 255, 0))` .